# Optimal Piecewise Linear Upper Bound for a function

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, dynamic-programming

I am looking for the optimal piecewise linear upper bound for a single variable function $f(x)$ - specified as a list of $(x,f(x))$ pairs. So, I have $(x_1,f(x_1)),(x_2,f(x_2)), \ldots, (x_n,f(x_n))$.

1. The piecewise approximation cannot have more than $L$ linear components, where $L$ is fixed number. I can solve the least squares fit via a dynamic programming problem, but not sure how it can be extended to upper bound.
2. Is there a way to regularize the problem so that I do not end up with large number of small line segments?

Comment: Is it sure that the value of the function between two consecutive points does not exceed the interpolation between those points?

Comment: One might be able to solve this in a similar manner as one of the [convex hull algorithms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) (maybe by taking the polar coordinates of the pairs of points, though this doesn't ensure L points).